# Single compile output directory when using Intellij Application run and gradle 4.2.1

Tags: java, intellij-idea, gradle

I'm working on a legacy project that was built using gradle 1.7 and the idea plugin for gradle. In the .idea directory there was a modules.xml which specified the Java compile output directory which compiled all the sub-projects into one root level out directory. However when updating to gradle 4.2 a new modules directory is generated and all output for the module is put in an out directory per sub-project.

Is there anyway to define where sub-projects out directory is using gradle 4.2.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out you still have to rely on the idea plugin and cant remove it completely.  The solution to get it working was to add

```
subprojects {
    apply plugin: 'idea'

    idea {
        module {
            inheritOutputDirs = true
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
android {
    applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        variant.outputs.each { output ->
            output.outputFile = new File(path_to_filename, output.outputFile.name)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer though I figured it out in the end.  Posted the answer below